# Exporting SQL data via BCP delimitted HL7

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have the following HL7 message from SQL output stored in the $Message variable:

```
MSH|^~\&|System|System CRM|SYS|System CRM|20210222143236||ADT^A04|CRM001|P|2.4|||AL|NE
EVN||20210222143236
PID||9999999997^^^^NHSN|Ben^Smith^^^Mr||||||12A Cherry Avenue^Middleton^London^Greater London^E170RA^NSP^P|||
PD1|||^Amazing Surgery, Amazing Health Centre, London, E16 0RA|^DR. Fix
PV1|1|O
```

I'm trying to create the output to txt file for it:

```
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Message = 'SELECT Message FROM #HL7'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000);
SELECT @sql = 'bcp ' + @Message + ' queryout "D:\HL7\Test.txt" -c -t|^ , -T -S'+ @@servername
PRINT @sql
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sql
```

However, i seem to get the following error

```
' ' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When remove the |^ I get:

```
Copy direction must be either 'in', 'out' or 'format'.
```

Please can someone help I think the delimited is causing issues

Comment: That's how SQL injection attacks happen and why `xp_cmdshell` is disabled by default and SHOULD NOT be enabled. What would happen if `@Message` contained `format c: /u` ? Or `del * /s` ? Stop using `xp_cmdsel` to begin with. The problem has nothing to do with the HL7 string

Comment: To understand what happened, check what `@sql` contains: `bcp SELECT Message FROM #HL7 queryout .....`. That's clearly invalid. The query should be quoted. If you used eg SQL Server Agent or Scheduled Tasks, you could just write a line with the command you need without any security risks, and even use a restricted account that can only read from the database and write to a specific folder

Comment: Thanks I dont believe there is an issue withthe HL7 message.  Its the BCP command.  I understand the risks with SQL injection, is there another method you would suggest in exporting to file?  I did think of a SSIS package but they are thousands of these messages created didnt think it would be the best option

Comment: If you understand the issues, why introduce them? Why did you re-enable `xp_cmdshell`? That command is turned off by default for 15 years, if not more.

Comment: OK in your experience then what would you suggest in terms of extraction to file?  SSIS?

Comment: I already explained you can use `bcp` from SQL Server Agent or Windows Scheduled Tasks. That's what you were trying to do right now - go to the command line and run `bcp`. Why not do that with the proper tools?

Comment: I'm sorry but you on about security risks with xp_cmdshell then telling me to run it form SQL agent (which it will be eventually).  Currently I'm writing SP to export it.  I'll just carry on trying to work a solution....

Comment: Which means your command will run using the same privileges as the SQL Server Service account, which can easily delete every data and log file. SQL Server Agent runs under a limited privilege account and even allows you to specify alternative accounts to execute specific jobs or tasks, like executing a CMD command. In this case, it's a lot easier to use SQL Server Agent to schedule `bcp 'select message from HL7; ...` than writing a stored procedure that does the same. If you want something more complex, you can create and run a Powershell script

Comment: Ignoring the security issues, to write dynamic tsql code you need to master tsql skills and you need to SEE what your dynamic code generates when an error occurs executing it. I suggest you start by writing a static BCP command line and getting that to work. You will see that attempting to use a local temp table is doomed so you will need to work around that. Or better yet - use (or research) ETL tools. Or revisit WHY you need to export this from the database into a file - maybe you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "' + @Message + '" queryout D:\HL7\Test.txt -c -t"|"^ , -T -S'+ @@servername
```

I have just exported data through below query:

```
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Message = 'SELECT *FROM test.dbo.table_name'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000);
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "' + @Message + '" queryout D:\HL7\Test.txt -c -t"|"^ , -T -S'+ @@servername
PRINT @sql
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sql
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks thats fantastic, think there is an issue with usage with temp tables though.  I created #HL7 and it doesnt work with it, but with normal tables it does

Comment: You have declared a local temp table which can only be referenced within current database session. You might try global temp table (##HL7). But that has also some limitation. You can check out local and global temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working implementation of what you're attempting:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.spSaveTextToFile') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE dbo.spSaveTextToFile
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spSaveTextToFile
  @TheString VARCHAR(MAX),
  @Filename VARCHAR(255),
  @Unicode INT=0
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @MySpecialTempTable VARCHAR(255)
  DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(4000)
  DECLARE @RESULT INT
 
--firstly we create a global temp table with a unique name
  SELECT  @MySpecialTempTable = '##temp'
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT(INT, RAND() * 1000000))
--then we create it using dynamic SQL, & insert a single row
--in it with the MAX Varchar stocked with the string we want
  SELECT  @Command = 'create table ['
       + @MySpecialTempTable
       + '] (MyID int identity(1,1), Bulkcol varchar(MAX))
insert into ['
       + @MySpecialTempTable
       + '](BulkCol) select @TheString'
  EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @command, N'@TheString varchar(MAX)',
           @TheString
 
--then we execute the BCP to save the file
  SELECT  @Command = 'bcp "select BulkCol from ['
          + @MySpecialTempTable + ']'
          + '" queryout '
          + @Filename + ' '
         + CASE WHEN @Unicode=0 THEN '-c' ELSE '-w' END
          + ' -T -S' + @@servername
  EXECUTE @RESULT= MASTER..xp_cmdshell @command, NO_OUTPUT
  EXECUTE ( 'Drop table ' + @MySpecialTempTable )
  RETURN @result
  GO
```

From [The TSQL of Text Files](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/) by Phil Factor

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through very useful.  Much appreciated